# apply function across rows for specific columns

Tags: r, tibble

I have tibble like:

```
t <- tribble(~name, ~salary, ~weight, 
             "sarah", 90000, 110, 
             "john", 50000, 150,
             "jones", 70000, 160, 
             )
```

I wish to divide `salary` by 1000, and weight (here in pounds) by 2.2, using a `weights` vector:

```
weights_ls <- c(1000, 2.2)
```

How do I divide the specific columns (`salary` and `weight`) by the `weights_ls` vector, row by row? `by_row`, for instance, doesn't seem to allow you to specify specific columns. For instance, I'd like to get:

```
| name | salary | weight |
|------|--------|--------|
| "sarah" | 90 | 50 |
| "john" | 50 | 68.1818 |
| "jones" | 70 | 72.7272 |
```

I'm not fussed about whether the answer creates new columns, or overrides existing columns.

Comment: `t` is not a good name for a data.frame since it is already the name of R's transpose function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to replicate the 'weights_ls' to make the lengths same and then divide

```
t[-1] <- t[-1]/weights_ls[col(t[-1])]
t
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#  name  salary weight
#  <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#1 sarah     90   50.0
#2 john      50   68.2
#3 jones     70   72.7
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to transpose the tibble, divide and transpose again

```
dt[2:3] <- t(t(dt[2:3])/weights_ls)

#  name  salary weight
#  <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#1 sarah     90   50.0
#2 john      50   68.2
#3 jones     70   72.7
```

If you are not aware about column positions you can also use column names

```
dt[c('salary', 'weight')] <- t(t(dt[c('salary', 'weight')])/weights_ls)
```

Or use `mapply`

```
dt[2:3] <- mapply(`/`, dt[2:3], weights_ls)
```

Or as suggested by @markus convert `weights_ls` to list and divide.

```
dt[2:3] <- dt[2:3]/as.list(weights_ls)
```

Renamed your tibble to `dt` as `t` is function name.